# How many Co-primes are here? With the next restrictions:

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem said:
How many integers in the set A = {1,2, … to 2015} are relatively prime to 2015?

I solve in a computational way, where by definition of co-prime I know that (gcd(n,2015) = 1) then I make a list and each gcd(n,2015)=1, the program sum and I had 1440 relative prime to 2015.

My question is that how can I get the same answer(I hope is correct), in a more 'fancy' way. In other word with more mathematical context (no program at all).

Comment: The number of numbers in the set ${1, 2, 3, \dotsc, n}$ which are relatively prime to $n$ are $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's Totient Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html). There are a number of interesting properties of this, one of which allows you to calculate $\phi(n)$ if you know the prime factorization of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The prime factors of $2015$ are $5,13,31$  Of the numbers less than or equal to $2015$, $4/5$ are coprime to $5$ and .....